# Cassandra tracing reads with python driver

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I'm working on an application using Cassandra and am trying to trace my queries to monitor execution speed.

I've been using the python driver from datastax and set up tracing

```
prepared_statement = session.prepare(statement)
cmd = prepared_statement.bind(binding_params)
result = session.execute(cmd, trace = True)
print 'Duration: ', result.get_query_trace().duration.total_seconds()
```

This works fine for upserts (inserts or updates). However, for select statements I get an error

```
Error from server: code=1000 [Unavailable exception] message="Cannot achieve 
consistency level LOCAL_ONE" info={'required_replicas': 1, 'alive_replicas': 
0, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File <source>, line 99, in processCQLRequest
    trace = result.get_query_trace()
  File "xxxx/python-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 4124, in get_query_trace
    return self.response_future.get_query_trace(max_wait_sec)
  File "xxxx/python-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3867, in get_query_trace
    return self._get_query_trace(len(self._query_traces) - 1, max_wait, query_cl)
  File "xxxx/python-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3882, in _get_query_trace
    trace.populate(max_wait=max_wait, query_cl=query_cl)
  File "xxxx/python-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 942, in populate
    SimpleStatement(self._SELECT_SESSIONS_FORMAT, consistency_level=query_cl), (self.trace_id,), time_spent, max_wait)
  File "xxxx/python-packages/cassandra/query.py", line 981, in _execute
    return future.result()
  File "xxxx/python-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3840, in result
    raise self._final_exception
```

I can tell that this is an issue with the consistency of one of the tables in the system keyspace, but is there any way for me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the Cassandra nodes could be down during your request. The inserts/updates proceeded fine because Cassandra is capable for storing hints when nodes are down within Cassandra cluster.

Check the output of "NODETOOL STATUS" command and make sure all nodes are up. If they have been down for longer period, try running repair before proceeding with query processing.

Comment: I checked - all nodes are up. 

Then odd ting is that the actual SELECT statements are executing fine. Select statements on my own keyspace are fine, but the following statement fails with a consistency error even though all nodes are up and running: 
    SELECT * FROM system_traces.sessions WHERE session_id = %s

https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/_modules/cassandra/query.html#tuple_factory